# Class Ranking by Statistics

Tags: normal-distribution

My daughter took a test and made a 266.  The max possible score was 300.  The mean was 242 with a standard deviation of 17.  I don't know how many scores are included, if it matters, but more than 1,000.

What can be determined about her class ranking based on this info? 
Thanks!!

Comment: How many questions on the test?  Do you know if the grades were normally distributed, or if there were offsets like "+10 for signing your name"?

Comment: I see you have added the "normal distribution" tag, but do you know if it really was normally distributed?

Comment: If there are more than a 1000 scores the distribution should be fairly Normal.

Answer (score 1):

Fun.  Note: standard disclaimers apply.

Knowns:

```
#knowns
grade_mean    <- 242
grade_std     <- 17
grade_sample  <- 266
grade_max     <- 300
```

So my first thing is to ignore her peers and look at the window she can have.  This presumes 1 point per correct question.

```
#libraries
library(prevalence)

#what percentile is her grade
b_test <- propCI(x=grade_sample,n=grade_max)
b_test
```

Here is techno-jargon.

```
> b_test
    x   n         p        method level     lower     upper
1 266 300 0.8866667 agresti.coull  0.95 0.8454742 0.9180820
2 266 300 0.8866667         exact  0.95 0.8452405 0.9202242
3 266 300 0.8866667      jeffreys  0.95 0.8471174 0.9188020
4 266 300 0.8866667          wald  0.95 0.8507954 0.9225379
5 266 300 0.8866667        wilson  0.95 0.8458006 0.9177555
```

The result (I prefer Jeffrey's prior) is that her "prevalence" or most likely actual level is about 88.7% of content was mastered.  The window for that is between 84.7% and 91.8%.  If the number of questions changes then this window changes.

Let's compare this to the class.

```
#what percentile is average grade
b_test2 <- propCI(x=grade_mean,n=grade_max)
b_test2
```

With results:

```
> b_test2
    x   n         p        method level     lower     upper
1 242 300 0.8066667 agresti.coull  0.95 0.7580501 0.8475289
2 242 300 0.8066667         exact  0.95 0.7573637 0.8497963
3 242 300 0.8066667      jeffreys  0.95 0.7591588 0.8482913
4 242 300 0.8066667          wald  0.95 0.7619790 0.8513544
5 242 300 0.8066667        wilson  0.95 0.7582162 0.8473627
```

Which mean their typical mastery is about 80.7% but the actual window ranges from 75.9% to 84.8%.

When I see that the lower edge of her window is so close to the upper edge of your daughter's then I think "she is substantially better than average".

Given the large number of samples, their grades, and the assumption of a Normal distribution I get this.

code + results:

```
> pnorm(q=grade_sample, mean=grade_mean, sd=grade_std)
[1] 0.9209904
```

translation:

It thinks she might be in the 92nd percentile.  This is only true if it is a normal distribution.  That is a big if.  Be careful with that.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your input.  The test was made up of 350 multiple choice questions of equal value.  The test was taken by 18,000 students.  Hopefully that answers the question of normal distribution.